# How do I print a TextFile OR contents of a TextBox in Metro apps?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a TextBox control in my Metro app and need to be able to simply print its contents. I have done my research ever since Windows 8 Dev Preview was around and I still cannot figure it out.

I've tried samples, read other answers and read the documentation - over, and over, and over. It just doesn't seem possible. So, after what, 2 years? I'm offering all my reputation (well, as much as they'll allow) in the hopes that someone can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print the contents of a TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563886/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-textbox) (I agree *that* question is not a duplicate, but I fail to see how *this one* is different from it.)

Comment: Please note that the comment above is in relation to the original version of this question (even though it's not really a duplicate). This question has yet to be answered; anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15616372/1230188 doesn't work for you ? What are you facing the problem in that?

Comment: I just don't understand it is all. There's so much code involved and I can't seem to grasp even the general idea about printing a TextBox so even though I can print using the sample, and run the sample, I can't sort of merge it or rewrite/copy it to use in my app because the very moment I start to do so, I'm no longer able to print.

Comment: I will upload the easiest sample or kind of library on GitHub as soon as possible.

Comment: Oooh thank you very much man. You are a very generous person. :)

Comment: @Xyroid any chance you've uploaded the sample to Git?

Comment: @Aeron it's on his original post (the one already pointed out as a possible duplicate)

Comment: @ChrisW., No it isn't, lol. On his other post he links to an old version (on Skydrive) which I couldn't get to work - that's not the one he's referring to in the comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have created a simple helper class which help you to print the `Textbox` content with its formatting. You just need to call static method of class `Printer`. The project on GitHub also contain test app.

```
await Printer.ShowPrintUIAsync(PrintPreview, MyTextBox, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

`PrintPreview` is a canvas, which is mandatory to show print preview in device charm. You have to declare in your XAML.

`MyTextBox` is a text box object, whose text content is going to be printed.

`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` is a file name for printing the document. (It will be applied if you are creating PDF or XPS file via printing.)

You can add helper class via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRT.TextboxPrintHelper/). If you want to enhance my existing helper class, fork on [GitHub](https://github.com/Xyroid/WinRT.TextboxPrintHelper)