# Print multiple documents in winrt

Tags: c#, printing, windows-runtime, components, windows-store-apps

I wrote a smal app to get sales from customers. Now I wan't to print a bill for ech customer.

I don't understand how I can set a pagebreak by code in winrt apps. Can anyone give me an example? Or is that not supported at the moment?

Or does there eist any free components for reporting or s.th.?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effor first.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Start of by having a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448418(v=vs.85).aspx and give the guides there a go. If you are still struggling, explain the problem and we'll help. As for reporting that's another question, I would ask that separately, same goes for pagebreak. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at these posts

[How to print the contents of a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563886/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-textbox)

[Print sample from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6)

[Printing from MVVM XAML Windows 8 Store apps - the final frontier](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/20/Printing-from-MVVM-XAML-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx)

Then if you face any problem, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Many thx for your suggestions. That looks great. I tried the samples, but I found them very strange and complex to understand. :)

Comment: What's your requirement for printing ?